# Build failed with error :Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach

Tags: ios, xcode

Build was running, but after some changes it started showing **build failed** with error:

```
/Users/mac007/Desktop/Projects/git@git.assembla.com: Internal error.
Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach  
"/var/folders/9p/bpyyfk3j2qj30wjd5lkp72rm0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-06-13_17-08-49_246000".

Steps to Reproduce:
On command+r  in Xcode 

Expected Results:
It should run but it is showing build failed

Actual Results:
It was showing Build failed

Version:
Xcode : Version 7.3 (7D175)
OS : 10.11.5 (15F34)
```

Comment: Wrong website: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: No response @Droppy

Comment: That's normal.  There is no point posting it here though.

Comment: @Droppy What will be the solution for this as it is not allowing me to run the project ?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens there isn't much you can do except try to identify what part of your project is giving it trouble and change it to something equivalent, but different.

1. Upgrade Xcode to 7.3.1 (you never know)
2. Go back to the last commit that built
3. Apply the next commit in as small increments as possible to try to figure out what it's having trouble with.
4. Write that part a different way.

Comment: Can you suggest me something ? I am facing same problem in JSQMessageViewController library...